# Counting textbox characters using a function

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

So I have been trying to get this working for 2 days now and still no luck.
I have a function that counts the characters of a textbox and display the results in a label.

```
function textCounter2(field, counter, maxlimit) {

    if (field.value.length > maxlimit)
        field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
    else
        document.getElementById('subtitlecount_lbl').innerText = maxlimit - field.value.length;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to use (input variable counter) inside getElementByID instead of manually typing subtitlecount_lbl.

I need to use the same function for about 15 textbox and labels.

Comment: Is `subtitlecount_lbl` a `textarea` element or some other non-input element (like a `div`, `span`, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working fine. Maybe it is a problem with the correct parameter handover.

```js
function textCounter2(field, counter, maxlimit) {
    if (field.value.length > maxlimit) {
        field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
    } else {
        document.getElementById(counter).innerText = maxlimit - field.value.length;
    }
}
```

```html
<input name="test" onkeyup="textCounter2(this, 'subtitlecount_lbl', 5)" onchange="textCounter2(this, 'subtitlecount_lbl', 5)" /><br />
<span id="subtitlecount_lbl"></span> characters left
```

Comment: yes here you have it as a "span" what if it was asp.net label

Comment: I got it to work.. my problem was not putting quotes when calling function onchange.. thanks a lot!